# Remove smilies (not emojis!) from tweets string

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I want to remove emoticons in my data that contains only text containing tweets. Each line corresponds to one tweet.
I get a bad character error for the ":)".

```
error: bad character range :-) at position 4
```

What is wrong?

```
#remove emoticons
import re
emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
        u":)"
        u":-)"
        u":D"
        u":("
        u":-("
        "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
with open('C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/test/data_sentiment.csv',"r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile1, open('C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/test/data_sentiment_stripped_emoticons.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile1:
    for line in oldfile1:
        line=emoji_pattern.sub(r'', line)
        newfile1.write(line)
newfile1.close()
```

Comment: your regex has some serious problem

Comment: Please include the real error message in your question. There are multiple things that _could_ be the problem; it's currently not clear which one you're asking about.

Comment: @AmeyYadav: How to fix it?

Comment: @Rawing: I added it in the original post.

Comment: Your code is horribly broken, I would suggest considering a complete re-do... Also your question is unclear, the title says "Remove smilies (not emojis!)" — what do you think  is? It's in the regex pattern.

Comment: the emoji is not the problem. I would like to get input on the smilies.

Comment:  is an emoji. The title of your question states not to remove emojis, but your code does...

Comment: I found my solution already and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

The bad character is actually on the previous line, the non-ASCII character.  If you want to use those, you need to declare a compatible encoding.  Search "Python character encoding" for the variety of choices you have.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
#remove emoticons 
with open('C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/test/data_sentiment.csv',"r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile1, open('C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/test/data_sentiment_stripped_emoticons.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile1:
    for line in oldfile1:
        line=line.replace("","").replace(':)', '').replace(':D', '').replace(":(","").replace(":-(","")
        newfile1.write(line)
newfile1.close()
```